# How to align backslashes, equals etc. in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, emacs

I want to align backslashes or equals like Emacs in Qt Creator. How can I do that?
Example Code:

```
#define CHECK(n)        \
  switch (n)            \
  {                     \
  case 0:               \
    cout << 0 << endl;  \
    break;              \
  case 1:               \
    cout << 1 << endl;  \
    break;              \
  case 2:               \
    cout << 2 << endl;  \
    break;              \
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator [natively supports clang-format](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-beautifier.html), which aligns backslashes as you desire.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand that. Can you give me information?

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the text, then `M-x align-regexp \\ RET`.